# My python code is saying things after an if which isn’t answered

Tags: python, if-statement

```
name = input("Hey whats your name")
print ("Oh hey" + name)
mood = input("How are you?")


if mood == ("Good") or ("good") or ("Good thanks") or ("Good thank you"):
  print("Thats great!")


if mood == ("Bad") or ("bad") or ("Not  great"):
  print("Ah thats not good")
  
if mood == ("Ok") or ("Alright") or ("Fine"):
  print("Oh ok well at least its not bad!")
```

Does anyone know why it’s printing “Ah that’s not good” and “ Oh ok well at least its not bad!” when good is answered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 2):

You must check the condition like this:

```
if mood == ("Good") or mood == ("good") or mood == ...
```

If you don't want to be case sensitive it is better to check like this:

```
if mood.lower() == "good" or mood.lower() == ...
```

The problem with your code is that the following expressions of your if will be casted to `bool` and an non empty string is not `False`

As bracco23 statet it is even better to use a `list` and check it like this:

```
if mood.lower() in ['good', 'good thanks', '...']:
```

Comment: Another option for easier checking: `mood.lower() in ["good", "good thanks", "good thank you"]`

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the equality operator applies only to nearby element (check Operators Priority topic). So for each "or" you need next "==" so as to work on booleans instead of strings.
E.g:

```
mood == ("Bad") or mood==("bad") or mood==("Not  great")
```

Also, don't hesitate to use additional brackets if you hesitate:

```
(mood == ("Bad")) or (mood==("bad")) or (mood==("Not  great"))
```

Btw., the brackets around string are not required:

```
(mood == "Bad") or (mood=="bad") or (mood=="Not  great")
```